# Moving mean within certain window while preserving Date, R

Tags: r, date, moving-average

I have a large rasterstack of 50 layers and I want to calculate the mean and max withing a moving window of 10. What I want for example is to calculate the mean for layers 1:10 and for 11:20 and so on (so in total 5 mean rasters). At the same time, I want to keep the dates of my layers based on the function that I use (e.g. the date of the rasters with the max value or the the mean date).

So far I have tried the following but is very slow. 
Can anyone hep me to do this more efficiently?

Considering `s_all` as my raster stack:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  t[[i]]<-calc(
            s_all[[((i-1)*10 + 1):((i-1)*10 + 10)]], 
            fun = mean, na.rm = T)
  t@z$Date[[i]]<-mean.Date(as.Date(
                              c(s_all@z$Date[[((i-1)*10 + 1)]],
                              s_all@z$Date[[((i-1)*10 + 10)]])))
}
```

**EDIT** 
Sample data

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1:100)
s_all <- stack(replicate(50, r))
d<-sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 50)
s_all<-setZ(s_all,d[],"Date")
```

Comment: Please provide sample data using `dput`.

Comment: Apologies, I am new user, I will try to create an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want a "moving average", but that is not what you describe (a moving average would return the same number of layers, with locally smoothed values). What you describe is an aggregation of layers with a step of 10. You can get that with `stackApply` or `aggregate`.

I changed your example data to have some variation in the values, and I do not randomize the dates.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
s <- stack(lapply(1:50, function(i) setValues(r, i)))
d <- seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day")[1:50]
s <- setZ(s, d, "Date")
```

For `stackApply` you need an index:

```
idx <- rep(1:5, each=10)
ss <- stackApply(s, idx, mean)
```

Given that the number of layers aggregated is constant, you can also use `aggregate`

```
sss <- aggregate(s, c(1,1,10), mean)
```

Now, set a new date, here I use the maximum.

```
newd <- tapply(getZ(s), idx, max)
newd <- as.Date(newd, origin="1970-01-01")
ss <- setZ(ss, newd, "Date")

ss
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 10, 10, 100, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : memory
#names      : index_1, index_2, index_3, index_4, index_5 
#min values :     5.5,    15.5,    25.5,    35.5,    45.5 
#max values :     5.5,    15.5,    25.5,    35.5,    45.5 
#Date       : 1999-01-10, 1999-01-20, 1999-01-30, 1999-02-09, 1999-02-19
```